# Visual Studio all references broken on GitHub clone

Tags: git, winforms, github, visual-studio-2019, devexpress

A colleague made WinForms application in Visual Studio 2019 and committed it to GitHub. I was asked to make requested changes to the application so I cloned the application from GitHub into Visual Studio. DevExpress controls are used in the application and both the computers have the same install of DevExpress.

When the cloning was complete I opened the solution and discovered that all the references in the project, that referenced to files outside of the project directory, had broken. I looked at the references on my colleague's computer and the paths of the references would all be valid on my computer as well as his.

[image]

I copied the project directory from his computer to mine directly via the network, and everything worked fine and I was able to build.

Does Visual Studio not sync the references with GitHub? Or do references not get cloned properly from GitHub?

I would like to be able to quickly clone a repository from GitHub and build right away with no issues, any ideas?

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but do you have DX 19.1 installed on your machine?

Comment: yes, I do. ''I copied the project directory from his computer to mine directly via the network, and everything worked fine and I was able to build."

Comment: Check the different in path of 2 installation on 2 PCs.

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress assemblies are placed into the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) by default so I guess your colleague installed their products globally and therefore they have these assemblies accessible. Here is an article that describes how the .NET framework resolves assemblies.
If you need just to build the application the simplest way to address the issue is using [DevExpress NuGet feeed](https://nuget.devexpress.com/) instead of just referencing the assemblies.
However, if you need to be able to open design-time forms you need to install DevExpress products using their installer. As far as I know, their NuGet assemblies support design-time only if you are using .NET 5.

Comment: Please note that I can copy the solution folder over the network and use it as expected, just not syncing it through GitHub.

Comment: I can suppose that when you copied the project you also got the /bin directory while in the most cases this directory is not synchronized by git (because of the .gitignore rules).
Can you check whether the bin directory is persists on the network copy?